# How to add observer to find navigation bar show and hide

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have `MapViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I push to multiple view controllers from this view controller, pop to `MapViewController` from these view controllers.

In `MapViewController` I have google map its top position starts from `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. I hide and show the navigation controller based on multiple conditions. For example when I show subview1 I hide the navigation bar, when I show subview2 I show the navigation bar, etc...

Now I want to change the mapview top position whenever the navigation bar is visibility is changed.

How to solve this?

- I checked [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate). There is no delegate method called when navigation bar is shown/hidden where I can update the mapview top position.
- `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not called when navigation bar visibility changed.
  I want to do this in `MapViewController` only. Not in pushed view controller from this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a **property observer** to the `isHidden` property of `navigationBar` and then observe any changes made, i.e.

```
var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.observer = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.observe(\.isHidden, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (navigationBar, changes) in
        if let newValue = changes.newValue {
            print(newValue)
            topConstraint.constant = newValue ? 0 : self.view.safeAreaInsets.top
        }
    })
}
```

When any changes are made in the `isHidden` property of `navigationBar`, we'll get a callback in the closure and act accordingly.

Comment: This closure is called when I hide/show the navigation bar. But always I'm getting 44 for print(self.view.safeAreaInsets.top) inside the closure

Comment: What else do you need then? You need to handle the show/hide of the navigationBar according to your requirements.

Comment: As I said I want to change the mapview top position. Need to get 0 for `self.view.safeAreaInsets.top` when navigation bar is hidden and 44/somethingelse when navigationbar is shown. So that I can use `topConstraint.constant = self.view.safeAreaInsets.top`

Comment: You can simply set the `topConstraint.constant = 0` with `safe area`. It will adjust automatically whenever the `navigationBar` hide/show. No need to observer the show/hide status of `navigationBar`.

Comment: May I know why have you marked the answer as negative? The question was about observing the show/hide property of navigationBar as represented in the title. And the answer given by me is a solution to that. Then what is the reason to downvote it? You don’t just downvote an answer if it doesn’t solve your whole project requirements I guess.